# How do I create the AuthorityKeyIdentifier from the public key in C?

Tags: c, openssl, authoritykeyidentifier

I'm creating a **self signed** certificate using openssl.

I created a key pair using the openssl function [`RSA_generate_key()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_generate_key.html):

```
key = RSA_generate_key(1024, 65537, null, 0);
```

Now, I want to generate the [Authority Key Identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.1) for the **self signed** certificate.

The RFC says:

> The value of the keyIdentifier field SHOULD be derived from the
> public key used to verify the certificate's signature or a method that generates unique values.  Two common methods for generating key
> identifiers from the public key are described in Section [4.2.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.2).

Okay. Let's have a look. In the mentioned section 4.2.1.2, the description says:

> (1) The keyIdentifier is composed of the 160-bit SHA-1 hash of the
> value of the BIT STRING subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag,
> length, and number of unused bits).

> (2) The keyIdentifier is composed of a four-bit type field with
> the value 0100 followed by the least significant 60 bits of
> the SHA-1 hash of the value of the BIT STRING
> subjectPublicKey (excluding the tag, length, and number of
> unused bits).

**If I'd want to use version (1): how do I obtain the data to be hashed in order to create a valid Authority Key Identifier?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create your certificate.
Then add the authority key identifier extensions has following :

```
add_ext(YourX509SelfSignedCert, NID_authority_key_identifier, "keyid,issuer");
```

you could also only use keyid,
There is an good article about which one to use [here](http://www.v13.gr/blog/?p=293)